# List pagination using jQuery Pagination

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-pagination

I'm working on .Net MVC project. I'm in need to show list for multiple divs with paging feature. Please see below for an example:

I want to show three projects at a time, and paging to show next divs. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: i'm fetching the contents from db and showing in html.
I don't knw how to add paging.

Answer (score 3):

I have done this using [List.js](http://www.listjs.com/)

```
<div id="listId">
  <ul class="list">
      // A bunch of items
  </ul>
  <ul class="pagination"></ul>
</div>

<script>
  var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'name', 'category' ],
    page: 3,
    plugins: [
      ListPagination({})
    ]
  };

  var listObj = new List('listId', options);
</script>
```